# Convergence of norm integral in R^4

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics, improper-integrals

I am working on a problem which have lead me to the following integral:

$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \epsilon^{8}\int_{E_{\epsilon}}\parallel{x}  \parallel ^{-12}\cos(x_{1})dx \, , $$ where$E_{\epsilon } =\left\{ x=(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})\in R^{4} \, : \, \parallel x\parallel\geq \epsilon \, \right\}$.The norm should be regarded as euclidean norm.
I am trying to check the exisitence of the limit using integration by part, but still can't give a clear answer. If it converges, please help give the value.

Comment: I assume you mean that 4-tuple as a typical element of $R^4.$ If so, maybe using subscripts rather than superscripts for the components would be clearer.

Comment: Write $\cos (x_1) = 1 - (1 - \cos (x_1))$. Note that $\lvert 1- \cos (x_1)\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{2} x_1^2 \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\lVert x\rVert^2$. Compute $$\int_{E_\epsilon} \lVert x\rVert^{-n}\,dx$$ for $n \in \{12,10\}$ to get the result.

Comment: Thanks for your useful comment. But how to get the value of the limit.You use an inequality ,so it is impossible to give the value. Is there anyone can help out a detailed solution? I am really new to this kind of subject.

Comment: If $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm then use Spherical coordinate to find the value of the integral first and then take the limit. Spherical formulas in $4$-dim. are given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{ E_\epsilon}\|x\|^{-12} \cos ( x_1 )  dx = \int_{ E_\epsilon}\|x\|^{-12}(1-(1- \cos ( x_1 ))  dx=\int_{ E_\epsilon}\|x\|^{-12} dx-\int_{ E_\epsilon}\|x\|^{-12}(1- \cos ( x_1 )) dx$$
We know from [@Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer) that $\lvert 1- \cos (x_1)\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{2} x_1^2 \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\lVert x\rVert^2$. Therefore,$$  |\int_{ E_\epsilon}\|x\|^{-12}(1- \cos ( x_1 )) dx|\leq  \frac{1}{2}\int_{ E_\epsilon}\|x\|^{-10}  dx$$
Hence,$$\int_{ E_\epsilon}\|x\|^{-12} dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_{ E_\epsilon}\|x\|^{-10}  dx\leq\int_{ E_\epsilon}\|x\|^{-12} \cos ( x_1 )  dx\leq\int_{ E_\epsilon}\|x\|^{-12}   dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_{ E_\epsilon}\|x\|^{-10}  dx$$
$$lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}}\epsilon^{8} (\frac{\pi^2  }{4\epsilon ^8} -\frac{\pi^2  }{3\epsilon ^6})\leq lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \epsilon^{8}\int_{E_{\epsilon}}\parallel{x}  \parallel ^{-12}\cos(x_{1})dx\leq lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}}\epsilon^{8} (\frac{\pi^2  }{4\epsilon ^8} +\frac{\pi^2  }{3\epsilon ^6})$$
$$\int_{ E_\epsilon}\|x\|^{-12} \cos ( x_1 )  dx=\frac{\pi^2  }{4}$$
Thanks for all your help.